# Move header to top when click button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sticky header that has a "button" appear after you scroll a certain amount. I want that button to move the header back to the top on user click, but I want the page to stay at the position it is at.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZyKar/655/

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
var y = $(this).scrollTop();
if (y > 55) {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeIn();
} else {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeOut();
}});$("body a.rep").live('click', function(){$(this).parents('#header').hide().prependTo("body").slideDown();});
```

Comment: You can see my answer. I updated it and it works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your script to....

```
var closed = false;

$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 55 && !closed) {
        $('.bottomMenu').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.bottomMenu').fadeOut();
    }

});

$("div.bottomMenu").on('click', function(){
    $('#header').css('position','static');
    $('div.bottomMenu').hide();
    closed = true;
});
```

Notice that I change the position of the header to static and attached the click event to the div instead of the `anchor`. You might want to re-factor this and use css classes instead of manipulating css properties directly. 
Also, I wrapped the header inside a block `div` so it nicely preserves some space for the header rather than using margins.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyKar/720/)**

Comment: this is great, but how do you prevent the button from showing up again after you have clicked it?

Comment: Use a flag to determine whether the button should be shown or not...http://jsfiddle.net/ZyKar/688/

Answer (score -1):

Do not use .live() use .on(). .live() is deprecated. Look **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyKar/705/)** for demo.

```
var clicked_btn = false;

$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(clicked_btn) 
    {
        if(y < 55)
        {
            clicked_btn = false;
            $('#header').css('position','fixed');
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        if (y > 55) 
        {
            $('.bottomMenu').fadeIn();
        } 
        else 
        {
            $('.bottomMenu').fadeOut();

        }
    }
});
$("a.rep").on('click', function(){
    $('#header').css('position','relative');
    $(this).parent().hide();
    clicked_btn = true;
});
```

I change position css property of header so it will go up, when you click x anchor tag. And then I hide parent of anchor tag (It will change display property of css to none). And record of anchor tag to clicked_btn as True. And on the scroll event of window I am checking state of anchor tag if it is false your logical code will be executed and if it is true and position of scroll bar is less than 55px it will change state of anchor tag to false and set back css property of header to fixed.